# Apache RewriteRule with url parameters

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

1.Can I use RewriteRule with url parameters ?
`Ex: www.foo.com/user/admin/?html=edit`
where: html=edit used to display form to edit user profile.

---

2.Can I find a good docs about RewriteRule apache module.

Comment: a basic google search would turn up the mod_rewrite docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

yes you can,

Simple add the following in your .htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On 

 RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*) index.php?module=user&section=$2 [L]
```

now in your index you'll find the get params sent as get params you can also access it via $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Comment: please notice there's a linebreak between RewriteEngine On and RewriteRule

Comment: not clear what you are going to do with mod_rewrite. Try to google with the words: rewriterule querystring