# Use text from URL after slash as parameter - htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite this:

```
http://example.com/new/location/
```

to:

```
http://example.com/new.php?p=location
```

Btw it could be anything after new/ for example i need:

```
http://example.com/new/anything
```

to actually be:

```
http://example.com/new.php?p=anything
```

But i need to keep the URL structure with the slashes for SEO and security purposes

How could i achieve this using .htaccess?

currently in my htaccess ive got:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /dir/
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache RewriteRule with url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754787/apache-rewriterule-with-url-parameters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following directive into your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^new/location$ new.php?p=location [L]
```

or to work any values use:

```
RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ new.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: the word location could be anything else, how could i have it more dynamic if lets say the url was new/address which would be new.php?p=address

Comment: Then simply replace the word location with $1 - that means there could be anything. RewriteRule ^new/(.*)$ new.php?p=$1 [L]